# Square roots in python

Tags: python

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(4)
2.0
```

Why does Python not give the negative square roots (as -2 is also a square root of 4)?
And how can I make Python to give out negative square roots?

Comment: Uh. There are no negative square roots. While the polynomial `x2 - 4 = 0` does have two roots, `2` and `-2`, the square root *function* itself only has one value and it's defined to be the positive one.

Comment: you can use `-math.sqrt(4)` to get what you want

Comment: To correct my previous comment: while the number `4` does have two square roots, the "square root *function*" is only defined to return the positive one. (Because a mathemathical function can only have value for a given input.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
def my_sqrt(x):
    root1 = math.sqrt(x)
    root2 = -root1
    return root1,root2
```

Comment: Another possible option is to use [numpy.root](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)

Answer (score 10):

If you need all the roots of a number, you can  use [numpy.root](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> def root(n, r):
    p = [1] + [0] * (r - 1) + [-n]
    return numpy.roots(p)

>>> root(4, 2)
array([ 2., -2.])
>>> root(-4, 2)
array([ 0.+2.j,  0.-2.j])
>>> root(1, 3)
array([-0.5+0.8660254j, -0.5-0.8660254j,  1.0+0.j       ])
```

Another option is to use [Sympy Polynomial Module](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/polynomials.html)

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, solve
>>> solve(x**2 - 4)
[-2, 2]
>>> from sympy import symbols, solve
>>> solve(x**2 - 4)
[-2, 2]
>>> solve(x**3 - 1)
[1, -1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2, -1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2]
>>> solve(x**2 + 4)
[-2*I, 2*I]
```

Comment: `root(1, 3)` means cube root?

Comment: @confused: Yes its cube root

Answer (score 4):

This is not something that's unique to Python, or to the square root function. This is an issue that comes up any time we are dealing with the inverse of a function that is not "injective". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

That is, the inverse of any function in which more than one value of x the maps to the same value of y, y=x**2 being just one example.

You could make the same complaint about many other functions, inverse sin (arcsin) for example. What is the value of "x" that make sin(x)=0.5? Even if we only consider a span of +/- 180 degrees (+/- pi) then there are two solutions, x=30 degrees and x=150 degrees. But implementations of inverse sin will always return only 30 degrees (pi/6). If we want the "other inverse" then we usually just use our knowledge of the particular function to obtain it.

For inverse square (sqrt) it's as simple as slapping a unary minus in front of it. For inverse sin, its taking the supplementary angle, pi-arcsin(0.5) for example.

Comment: `sin` is a little harder as there are an infinite number `x` such that `sin(x) = y`

Comment: @mgilson That why I said "**even if we only consider the span +/- 180 degrees**". That is, one revolution of the circle, there are still two inverse sin values!

Comment: Yep :). Sorry, I only read your first paragraph and your last one ... I guess that's what I get for reading too many scientific papers.  ... Abstract ... *turns pages* ... Conclusion ... *Hmm ... Interesting ...*