# Value Error: math domain error in Python

Tags: python, math, python-idle, sqrt

I'm writing a code to help me solve the Pythagorean theorem in Python. Problem is, I keep getting this one error when I have the code try solving for B.

This is the bit that always gives me problems:

```
bsqr = (int(c) ** 2) - (int(a) ** 2)
b = int(bsqr) / sqrt(bsqr)
```

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module> pythag()
 File "C:\Python34\fact.py", line 156, in pythag
 b = int(bsqr) / sqrt(bsqr)
 ValueError: math domain error
```

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Show the full code. There might be a / by 0 or something like that.

Comment: This may be too basic, but a very useful debugging tool is to `print` out all the variables.  In this case, `print(a, c, bsqr)` should give you a pretty big clue..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely because `bsqr` is negative and taking the sqrt of a negative number doesn't work too well.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Check your algebra/inputs.  `c` (the hypoteneuse) should *always* be bigger than either of the legs (`a` and `b`)

---

Also, side note, you could also get a `ZeroDivisionError` if you happen to put in values for `a` and `c` which are equal (after `int` truncates them).

Comment: `i` (or `j`) disagree!

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- It works mathematically, but not with `math.sqrt` ;-).  But clever comment none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this:

[Square roots in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392128/1447634)

Also see the [cmath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) module in Python

[cmath module - sqrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt)